# Box.net integration issue in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cloud

anybody having idea to integrate box.net cloud, I used to get the login but when i navigate to different screen,the session expires showing ths message:"Login was completed in BoxLoginViewController and it tried to notify its delegate, but the delegate was nil or boxLoginViewController:didFinishWithResult: has not been implemented."

Comment: whereas the new box.net framework causes crash as the setKey method is set in the Appdelegate. But in the sample provided by Box, its not crashing. Its really strange...